# Spring JPA Naming troubles

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

I have an issue which is driven me crazy. I have two apps (Taco Cloud example apps from Spring in Action 5, book) The jpa is working OK. It contain some scripts to generate database schema. One of the generated tables is named **taco_order_tacos**, it is all-key entity and the generated ids are : **order_id** and **taco_id**.  Exactly same script and same Entity objects fail in another project, because CrudRepository looks for a **tacos_id** (with s at the end of taco word, plural) when try to save an object (Order). By the way, both projects are using same spring-boot-starters dependencies. Of course adding "s" to taco_id (tacos_id) on failing project's taco_order_tacos table, it is working fine, but I need to understand what is going on.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is error stack:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into taco_order_tacos (order_id, tacos_id) values (?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into taco_order_tacos (order_id, tacos_id) values (?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.lm2a.tacos.OrderController.processOrder(OrderController.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1333)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Columna "TACOS_ID" no encontrada
Column "TACOS_ID" not found; SQL statement:
insert into taco_order_tacos (order_id, tacos_id) values (?, ?) [42122-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:703)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumn(Parser.java:1450)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnList(Parser.java:1435)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsertGivenTable(Parser.java:1804)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1749)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:352)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    ... 87 more
```

EDITION TO ADD SOME CODE:

Here is the class which is creating the conflict, but is exactly same class on OK project. As you can see, there are no columns/table renaming, so IMO, there is no point to try to make an insert on Tacos_ID, when table name is Taco:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Taco {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min=5, message="Name must be at least 5 characters long")
  private String name;

  private Date createdAt;

  @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Ingredient.class)
  @Size(min=1, message="You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
  private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

  @PrePersist
  void createdAt() {
    this.createdAt = new Date();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you run a diff between the source code of the two projects?

Comment: I was basically copying from the OK project to the KO project, and I can assure all Repositories interfaces, and all Entities and even POM´s are identical. There is a better way to compare two projects that Eclipse compre with each other at project level?

Comment: There are three repositories for three objects, all of them are the same, three domain entities (repositories are to persist them), copied too, same application.properties and same dependencies on POM´s, but in one case ask for tacos_id asnd in the other one, just taco_id. I have no idea where can be the difference.

Comment: It would be easier if you just posted your code...

Comment: in the mapping do you declare the column's name? if you do not by default it might be nameOfEntity underscore id as in tacos_id or taco_id based on what the name of the Taco @Entity is

Comment: Here is the class which is creating the conflict, but is exactly same class on OK project: